# mongodb - storing relation with id

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, foreign-keys

I have a very basic (might be sily) question.
Suppose I am having product collection with list of product as below.

```
db.products.findOne
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60db1b449f9a43695c4bb461"),
    "name" : "product 1"
}
```

while storing category as a relation, how should it be stored? (Please check the category_id)

approach 1

```
db.products.findOne
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60db1b449f9a43695c4bb461"),
    "name" : "product 1",
    "category_id" : ObjectId("608f981fcfeaa757ca69b4b5")
}
```

approach 2

```
db.products.findOne
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60db1b449f9a43695c4bb461"),
    "name" : "product 1",
    "category_id" : "608f981fcfeaa757ca69b4b5"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

**Embed as `ObjectId` type if:**
You will perform `$lookUp` operations based on this key, then it's better to embed it as `ObjectId` type.

> I highly recommend embedding it as `ObjectId`

**Embed as `string` type if:**
The driver or application which you are using does not support working with the `ObjectId` type.

In the company I am working for, we have embedded relations as ObjectId, and even though it's easy to pass the data to REST API (since no conversion is needed), it's a big pain to convert string to ObjectId for `$lookUp` operations.

Note that in most of the languages, you have to handle errors additionally while converting string to ObjectId (since `ObjectId` has validation rules), whereas this problem is not present for converting `ObjectId` to `string`